# Сколько словосочетаний со связью согласование в предложении?

Tags: согласование, синтаксис, словосочетания

Сколько словосочетаний со связью согласование в предложении:

> Рукописная комедия Грибоедова "Горе от
> ума" произвела потрясающее впечатление
> и поставила его в ряд с лучшими
> поэтами.

Я думаю, что 3 - **рукописная комедия**, **потрясающее впечатление**, **лучшими поэтами**. Правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, правильно, остальные варианты - несогласованное определение и приложение.